# Issue detecting GPIB interface using PyVISA

Tags: python, gpib

I have an error while connecting my device using GPIB interface by PYvisa.Below is the simple code i run.

```
   >>> import visa;

   >>> rm = visa.ResourceManager('C:/Windows/System32/visa32.dll');

   >>> rm.list_resources();

   ('ASRL10::INSTR', 'ASRL71::INSTR')
```

But i don't see them getting detected as GPIB interface themselves.(like GPIB::25::INSTR).I have installed proper version of python and PyVISA. Below is the output for the same.

```
C:\>python -c "from pyvisa import util; util.get_debug_info()"
   Machine Details:
   Platform ID:    Windows-7-6.1.7600
   Processor:      x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

   Python:
   Implementation: CPython
   Executable:     C:\Python34\python.exe
   Version:        3.4.3
   Compiler:       MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)
   Bits:           32bit
   Build:          Feb 24 2015 22:43:06 (#v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601)
   Unicode:        UCS4

   PyVISA Version: 1.8

   Backends:
   ni:
      Version: 1.8 (bundled with PyVISA)
      #1: C:\Windows\system32\visa32.dll:
         found by: auto
         bitness: 32
         Vendor: National Instruments
         Impl. Version: 14680064
         Spec. Version: 5243904
      #2: C:\Windows\system32\visa32.dll:
         found by: auto
         bitness: 32
         Vendor: National Instruments
         Impl. Version: 14680064
         Spec. Version: 5243904
```

Googling, i found that version and library path may be the possible reasons. But i guess that is not the issue in my case. Can anyone point out where am i going wrong as i am very much new to Python and pyVISA.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your GPIB devices connected/detected via the NIMax panel. If it does not show up on the NIMax then your devices are not connected. 
Additionally you should not need to put the   visa32.dll path in visa.ResourceManager().